# Error when trying to build for iPhone simulator on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I fix the error mentioned below?

```
ld: warning: URGENT: building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file (/Users/amy/Desktop/amy/swift_proj/swift_proj/include/libcrypto_x86_64.a(asn1_lib.o)) built for OSX. Note: This will be an error in the future.
```

I assume that to run on iPhone simulator, we use arch type x86_64. Is that correct? The library I'm trying to link (libcrypto) is of arch type x86_64.

I've shown my Xcode build settings below:

```
Architectures: Standard architectures
Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 11.4)
Build active architecture only: No
Supported platforms: iOS
Valid architectures: arm64
```

I'm a newbie.

Comment: It isn't enough that the arch type is x86_64. OS X x86_64 and iOS x86_64 are different. You've got the wrong type.

Comment: Also, looks like this is a known issue, since it's still sitting open at https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL/issues/38

Comment: @matt I am also having similar issue. Any idea what should be  the arch type for iPhone simulator